# check if file exist on Sharepoint Online by File Name with Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a flow in Power Automate Cloud that allows me to extract some files from Google Drive and copy them to a Sharepoint folder. But before copying it, it has to check by the file name, that the file does not already exist in the sharepoint folder. I have managed to do the whole flow, except the checking.
I would be very grateful for your help.
Thank you very much. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `File exists` action doesn't currently exist but you can use the `Get file metadata using path` action from the `SharePoint` connector to do the same sort of thing.

This flow below shows you an example of what you can do ...

[image: Flow]

For demonstration purposes, I've created an array with a list of file names (full path required) that I will then test the existence for.

One of those files doesn't exist.

[image: File Names Array]

[image: Files]

I then loop through each one of those and try and get the metadata for each file.

If the resulting `statusCode` from the call to get the metadata is not equal to 200, then we know the file doesn't exist.

[image: Condition]

Examples ...

[image: Item 2]

[image: Item 3]

To make this work however, you need to make sure that the `Condition` step will execute after the metadata call no matter what the result.

Do this by making sure the `Configure run after` settings are correct ...

[image: Settings]

[image: Run After]

So after all of that, all you need to do is deal with the true and false sections of the condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have applied the steps you have indicated and I have been able to solve the problem.